# Is it possible to leverage the iOS System Keyboard when creating a Custom Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

Is it possible to use the Apple Native Keyboard as a base for a custom global Swift Keyboard extension?  The use case is a keyboard that adds something to the typing processing, but doesn't change the look and feel of native keyboard.

Requirement is to add functionality overlay while preserving all the great native keyboard usability features.

Comment: No, you have to implement all the functionality you want in your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at inputAccessoryView https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621119-inputaccessoryview

It's also available as a "settable/read-write" property on UITextField and UITextView so you don't have to do the "redeclare this property as read-write in a UIResponder subclass" dance as mentioned in the above link. Related is an optional inputAccessoryViewController.